# How does partial views work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

In a MVC master view I have this:

```
    @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)
```

and the partial view _CreateOrEdit contains this code block:

```
    @{
       var item = Model;
       .
       .
       .
       string favouriteId = "fav_" + item.Id + "_comment";
     }
```

Despite ensuring that item.Id > 0 I get a null reference error in pointing at the declaration of favouriteId. The dots mean there are many other similar declarations all with non null reference.

When I replace item.Id by @item.Id, rendering the partial views fail in the master view.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone point to a complete tutorial on code blocks please?

Thanks

Comment: You're asking the question the wrong way around. [_"Throw me all documentation and I'll figure it out"_ is not the way to go](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/02/02/10263027.aspx) (not in the first place because there hardly _is_ any documentation for MVC, you'll have to go read the source and the blogs). Create a small example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: have you added @model in your partial view?

Comment: @CodeCaster by your comment I assume there is nothing syntactically wrong with that block code?

Comment: @Mukund yes I have @@model in my partial view

Answer (score 0):

Another '@' cannot be used since the statement is already within the razor code block.

In order to avoid the object reference exception, use the below code

```
string favouriteId = string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", "fav", item.Id, "comment");
```